# Tensorflow: Filter a tensor out of a list of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using a dataset where I parse in four tensors from each tfrecord file. Every so often, one of the four tensors will be empty and I would like to be able to filter out this tensor and send the rest of the tensors to the next step in the tf.data pipeline. I keep the four tensors in a dictionary and I'd like to be able to do something like this.

```py
@tf.function
def filter_and_reshape(tensor_dict, shape):
    return {k: tf.reshape(t, shape)
            for k, t in tensor_dict.items() if not tf.equal(tf.size(t), 0)}
```

Where `tensor_dict` is a dictionary of the tensors I've just parsed from a file, but not yet restored to their original shape.

Unfortunately this does not work since `tf.equal(tf.size(t), 0)` returns a tensor not a bool, and it doesn't seem like autograph can fix the issue.

Is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: Does tf.data.Dataset.filter not solve your problem?

Comment: No because that is for filtering out an entire record. I want to filter out a tensor within a record.

Answer (score 0):

All elements produced by a `tf.data.Dataset` must have the same structure. e.g, if a dataset produces dictionaries with keys "a", "b", "c", "d", all elements produced by the dataset will always have those four keys. You can't produce some elements with 4 keys and other elements with 3 keys.

I suggest changing your model code to ignore the potentially-empty tensor if it is empty.

To add together 4 potentially-empty tensors, you can do

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_v2_behavior()

a = tf.constant([1, 1, 1])
b = tf.constant([2, 2, 2])
c = tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32)
d = tf.constant([7, 7, 7])

def add_py_fn(a, b, c, d):
  s = tf.zeros((3,), dtype=tf.int32)
  for t in [a, b, c, d]:
    if tf.size(t) > 0:
      s += t
  return s

def add_fn(a, b, c, d):
  return tf.py_function(add_py_fn, [a, b, c, d], tf.int32)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((a, b, c, d))
ds = ds.map(add_fn)
print(next(iter(ds)))
```

The py_function escape hatch is needed because the runtime can't tell that `c` will never be added to `s`, so it will throw a shape error otherwise.

Comment: You're correct that the output of the dataset always has to be the same, but you can change the shape of the data in the dataset pipeline itself. For example you could take 4 elements and then add them together and pass that to the model. What I'm asking for is the equivalent of only adding 3 when one of them is empty.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a way to add elements only if they are non-empty.

Comment: Thanks! You actually don't need a pyfunc for addition. You can check for emptiness using a `tf.cond` and then return a tensor of zeros in that case and add it. I was interested more generally in being able to filter out one of the tensors, but maybe that isn't possible. I thought the autograph might be able to help, but maybe not.